LM2596 Not Outputting Voltage
I'm making a PCB that will use a Buck Converter (LM2596) to step down the voltage from 12V to 5V. When I supply 12V to the PCB it gets fed into the LM2596 but the output is coming out to be around 44mV.
For Cin I'm using a 100uF Tant SMD, Cout a 220uF Tant SMD, a standard Schottky Diode, and a 47uH inductor. The schematic of the circuit is below.  I followed the general application schematic of the LM2596 found in its datasheet.

Could the issue be Cin? I see that the datasheet for the LM2596 uses a 680uF but I thought that is just to filter out noise so I used a 100uF Tant to reduce the footprint on the board.
Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
Down below is the layout for the PCB. I'm using a two layered board. Top board connections are highlighted in red and bottom board are highlighted in blue.
The LM2596 in question is located at the top of the board one for 5V an one for 3V. They both don't work so I isolated to just using the 5V one (left). The "Cin" capacitors are located at the bottom the board. The big square below the LM2596 is the inductor and below that is the Schottky diode. "Cout" can be located to the right of the Schottky diode--sandwiched between the 5V Schottky diode and the 3V Schottky diode.
It should be noted that I'm doing a copper pour for ground on both top and bottom layers but to show the schematic I took that away.




Chances are it's an implementation problem or a bad part. The schematic looks okay enough to give an output. Maybe post clear photos of the board and screen caps of the PCB layers. Did you buy the LM2596-5 chips from a franchised TI distributor or are they questionable?

This is a switching regulator. Only good PCB layout makes this kind of circuits to work properly. Show your PCB layout please.

@SpehroPefhany I bought the LM2596 chips from Digikey. Not to sure if they are a trusted distributor or not.

Those tiny little traces might've just instantly burnt up...

What is the full part number of the chip you bought?

@MathKeepsMeBusy for the 5V the LM2596SX-5.0/NOPB and the LM2596SX-3.3/NOPB.

@JonathanS. You bring up an interesting point. The current width of the 5V 3A is 3mil or .00254mm. When I test continuity through the traces between components, I get a beep from the multimeter that they are still connected. However, I'm still an amateur in PCB design so the suggestion that small of trace cannot handle the 3A is a valid one and I'll take it into consideration.

I don't know about "burnt up", but the layout is extremely suspect. You need to look at the examples on page 32 and adapt them for your parts. Tiny traces + ground pour can perform adequately for lots of circuits but absolutely will not cut it for a switching converter.


"I'm still an amateur in PCB design" -

Not only for amateurs, but  even for seasoned designers there is a concept of "suggested layout" that comes from manufacturers of a IC, and usually within provided datasheet. The datasheet not only contains suggested layouts (meaning that following it you can achieve the advertised parmeters)

but also frequently includes explanations (theory) why some critical traces must be as wide as possible:

Using 3mil traces should be an academic example of how NOT to design switching converters.
